# "Так называемый": в запятых или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "Об этом говорит(,) так называемый(,) «горизонтальный» техрегламент..." С одной стороны "так называемый" вроде бы вводное, но с другой запятые как-то тут сомнительны.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: Об этом говорит так называемый горизонтальный техрегламент..

"Так называемый" - это местоименное выражение, которое не является вводным и не выделяется запятыми. Также следующее за ним слово не заключается в кавычки.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Выражение "так называемый" имеет значение "условно называемый" и находится в неоднородных отношениях с последующим прилагательным "горизонтальный".